# how to remove uibaritem background image in IOS?

Tags: ios, image, uibarbuttonitem

Hi i used this code to set the background image for my bar button. I put it in "AppDelegate.h"

```
  //-- set bar button image
    UIImage *barButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-button"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 6, 0, 6)];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It worked fine but in my Search Controller I dont want to use it, because it make my "search" button look very ugly. Is there anyway to remove the background image in search controller only ? Plz helpe me. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: you can track subview of Seach controller NSArray *subviews = [view subviews]; and then remove background of whichever view you want..

Comment: how to remmove it can u give me example code thnks

Comment: i have added code plz see new answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

In your SearchController.m try

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[searchBarObject setImage:nil forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This work for me.. I hope it will be helpful for you..

Updated full code..
**.m file contents in viewDidLoad**

```
//Table initialization..........................................................................
    my_table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height)];

//SearchBar initialization......................................................................
UISearchBar *search = [UISearchBar new];
[search sizeToFit];
search.delegate = self;

//Make the image in size 20x20................................................................
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.jpg"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(20, 20), YES, 0);
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
UIImage *img2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Set the image for the UISearchbarIconSearch...................................................
[search setImage:img2 forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];

search.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[my_table setTableHeaderView:search];
[my_table reloadData];

//SearchDisplay initialization..................................................................
UISearchDisplayController *display = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:search contentsController:self];
sbc = display; //
display.delegate = self;
display.searchResultsDataSource = self;
display.searchResultsDelegate = self;

my_table.dataSource = self;
my_table.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:my_table];
```

**.h file.**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>

{
    NSArray *table_array;
    UITableView *my_table;
    UISearchDisplayController *sbc;
    NSArray *filtered;
}
@end
```

This is my code which change the search icon image...

Comment: what is searchBarObject?? I dont know how to define it ?

Comment: @tommy searchBarObject is instance of Search bar

Comment: @TamilKing I use this: [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setImage:nil forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal]; but it didnt work

Comment: I had this error  Use of undeclared identifier 'searchBarObject'

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove  background image of Search controller

```
[[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```

and you can add clear background image to it.

```
UIImageView *searchImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 319.0, 44.0)];
[searchImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbg.png"]];
[searchBar insertSubview:searchImage atIndex:1];
```

Comment: The first one is didnt work for me, the 2nd is only the border of the search bar is clear the background of button"Cancel" is still same

Answer (score 0):

You can set where you want the customization, for instance in tis snippet I only want it in UINavigationBar.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]setBackgroundImage:barButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Not checked in xcode but the concept is OK. Here the doc [+ (instancetype)appearanceWhenContainedIn:(Class )ContainerClass,...](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).
 Great guide also here: [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/).
As you can see is a variadic arguments API, so you can set more classes

PS: I don't know if it is a wanted effect, but the kind of reflection is due to wrong insets in the image.